# How to extend existing WiX projects in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wix

I have to extend a existing VS2008 project which includes many separate WiX 3.0 projects.
My concern is:

I would like to extend some of the VS-projects and make minor changes in the classes by overwriting them. Can I also extend the existing WiX project by inheritance?
I ask this because the existing WiX project is very large and complicated. So I want to make a WiX-project with only my modifications as easy as possible.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

John

Comment: It would help if you'D explained the kind of changes you want to make to your project: add another library, add another task to be executed while installing, etc?

Comment: Hi David, 
I'm only modifying a existing dll by adding new functionality and then I would like to deliver it as a msi together with the existing setup project msi's. There exists a large setup project, which includes a setup project for the original dll.
I would like to replace it with my dll. But I'm confused of the large setup project. I would like to know, if there is a easy way to update/extend the existing setup project.
I must admit that I'm not familiar with WiX projects.

Answer (score 0):

Wix doesn't know about the classes in your project. It only knows which files (and some other things like registry entries and shortcuts) that need to be installed.

So unless you are going to add new libraries to the project you should not have to make any changes to the wix files.

Comment: I have to add a modified dll. But unfortunately I can't edit the existing original setup project. So I have to create a new one.
I read in the manuals about updating a existing project. I will try this first. Thanks for the answer.